# Publish stream as a record using .flv and microphone

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5, netstream

At the beginning i would like to say sorry for my english.

I would like to publish stream as a record on my RED5 server but i have a problem because i want to save .flv + voice from my microphone on my server.

I'm trying to connect to my red5 server:

```
connection = new NetConnection();
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEventR5);
connection.client = this;
connection.connect("rtmp://" + my_ip);
```

and it's works of course (btw. listener for connection take information something like "Netstream.Connect.Failed" and so forth). Anyway after connect to server i'm trying to publish *flv video and my voice and then save this like:

```
stream = new NetStream(connection);
stream.client = this;
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEvent);
stream.bufferTime=0;
stream.play(filename);
stream.attachAudio(_micDevice.getMicrophone());
stream.publish(recfilename, "record");
```

When i looked on my server after stream i saw that file was saved but included only voice from my microphone, without screen or audio from .flv. It's possible? Any advices?

Comment: Did you forgot to attach the camera to your stream? [attachCamera()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#attachCamera())

Comment: But i want to play (stream) flv video from my server and add my microphone voice and then save all of this on my server.

Comment: So you want to create a recording with new voice audio and previously recorded video?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 0):

I know that's a little late to answer this question but I do for, may be, another person who need an answer.

I think that's impossible to play and publish over the same `NetStream`, adobe was clearly said :

```
Note:You cannot play and publish a stream over the same NetStream object.
```

See here for more details : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#badgeAnchorSupport